# Using text input by the user to access an array of that name?

Tags: javascript, arrays

As part of an assignment for uni i've been asked to write a question worth 10 marks and then write a solution and marking scheme for said question.

This is my question;

Write  a program that will store the top ranking fighters of 3 weight divisions in the UFC (using the following data);

-Featherweight; Connor McGregor, Jose Aldo, Frankie Edgar, Max Holloway, Anthony Pettis.

-Lightweight; Connor McGregor, Khabib Nurmagomedov, Tony Ferguson, Eddie Alvarez, Rafael dos Anjos.

-Light heavyweight; Daniel Cormier, Anthony Johnson, Alexander Gustafsson,  Ryan Bader, Glover Teixiera.

Prompt the user to enter the name of a weight division in the UFC and return the ranking the the format;

Current Champion is ….
1st contender is …..
2nd contender is ……
Etc.

So far in my solution for the questioni have had the user enter the name of a weight division, however i now have the problem of trying to use that specific variable in a loop.

This is my code so far;

***//Declaration of the arrays to store the ranking of the weight divisions;***

*var featherweight = ["Connor McGregor", "Jose Aldo", "Frankie Edgar", "Max Holloway", "Anthony Pettis"];*

*var lightweight = ["Connor McGregor", "Khabib Nurmagomedov", "Tony Ferguson", "Eddie Alarez", "Rafael dos Anjos"];*

*var lightHeavyweight = ["Daniel Cormier", "Anthony Johnson", "Alexander Gustafsson", "Ryan Bader", "Glovier Teixiera"];*

***//Declaring the output variable to store and add to what will be output before it is displayed;***

*var output = "";*

***//Variable to store the user input and a prompt to recieve the users input;***

*var userInput = prompt("Please enter the name of a weight devision you would like to see the rankings off. \n Options are; \n - featherweight \n - lightweight \n - lightHeavyweight");*

***//loop that will continue adding items to the output for the length of the array that the user has asked to see.;***

*for (var i = 0; i < )*

Help is greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Before the loop you should have chained [if statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else):

```
var chosenArray;
if (input === "x")
{
  chosenArray = xArray;
}
elseif (input === "y")
{
  chosenArray = yArray;
}
...
else
{
  // should print that the input is unknown
}
// should use chosenArray for loop
```

Comment: Ah so then is would put chosenArray.length when getting the limit for the loop?

Comment: sounds like a good idea. test your code and see if it solves the problem